# Why is my price box remembering what I typed in it the time before. I do not want this to happen. Any suggestions?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Why is my price box remembering what I typed in it the time before. I do not want this to happen. Any suggestions?
Here is my code. Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening. The second time I enter a price in pricebox it remembers the previous amount.

```
  Private Sub ProductIDComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboProductIDLookup.SelectedIndexChanged


    'Test to determine if a product has been selected
    If cboProductIDLookup.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then

        'Store the selectedIndex to variable
        Dim RowInteger As Integer = cboProductIDLookup.SelectedIndex

        'Based on RowInteger, display values to TextBox controls
        'from the array named inventoryProduct
        txtProductID.Text = InventoryProduct(RowInteger).ProductIDString
        txtDescription.Text = InventoryProduct(RowInteger).DescriptionString
        txtQuantityAmount.Text = InventoryProduct(RowInteger).QuantityInteger.ToString("N0")
        txtPriceAmount.Text = InventoryProduct(RowInteger).PriceDecimal.ToString("C2")

    End If
    ' txtQuantityAmount.Focus()
    txtPriceAmount.Focus()
    txtPriceAmount.Clear()



End Sub


    Private Sub txtPriceAmount_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtPriceAmount.KeyPress


    '''''''' Check for the flag being set in the KeyDown event.
    If acceptableKey = False Then
        '''''''' Stop the character from being entered into the control since it is non-numerical.
        e.Handled = True
        Return
    Else
        '''''''' 'must be in first position            

        If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back) Then

            If strCurrency.Length > 0 Then
                strCurrency = strCurrency.Substring(0, strCurrency.Length - 1)
            End If
        Else
            strCurrency = strCurrency & e.KeyChar
        End If

        If strCurrency.Length = 0 Then
            txtPriceAmount.Text = ""
        ElseIf strCurrency.Length = 1 Then
            txtPriceAmount.Text = "0.0" & strCurrency
        ElseIf strCurrency.Length = 2 Then
            txtPriceAmount.Text = "0." & strCurrency
        ElseIf strCurrency.Length > 2 Then
            txtPriceAmount.Text = strCurrency.Substring(0, strCurrency.Length - 2) & "." & strCurrency.Substring(strCurrency.Length - 2)
        End If
        txtPriceAmount.Select(txtPriceAmount.Text.Length, 0)

    End If
    e.Handled = True

End Sub

      Private Sub PurchaseToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PurchaseToolStripMenuItem.Click

    'Test to determine if a product was found.
    If txtDescription.Text = String.Empty Then

        'Cannot purchase, product was not found
        MessageBox.Show("You must select a valid product before purchasing.", "Cannot Purchase", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        txtProductID.Focus()
        txtProductID.SelectAll()
    Else
        'Can purchase the product

        Dim ProductString As String = txtProductID.Text.PadRight(12, " ") & "" & txtDescription.Text.PadRight(50, " ") & "" & txtQuantityAmount.Text.PadRight(7, " ") & "" & txtPriceAmount.Text.PadLeft(9, " ").ToString
        lstPurchaseItems.Items.Add(ProductString)

        ' Double.Parse(txtPriceAmount.Text).ToString("C2").PadLeft(9, " ")
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Accumulate the total value of this customer order
        'and display it to the output box
        TotalDueDecimal += (txtPriceAmount.Text.ToString * txtQuantityAmount.Text)
        txtTotalDueAmount.Text = TotalDueDecimal.ToString("C2")


        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


        'Accumulate total sales by product to an array
        Dim IndexInteger As Integer = cboProductIDLookup.SelectedIndex
        ProductSalesTotalDecimal(IndexInteger) += (txtPriceAmount.Text * txtQuantityAmount.Text)

        'Here you can clear the form of product info if you think
        'that is a good way to do the processing
        cboProductIDLookup.SelectedIndex = -1
        txtProductID.Clear()
        txtDescription.Clear()
        txtPriceAmount.Clear()
        txtQuantityAmount.Clear()
        txtProductID.Focus()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You really should use [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx). I see you're multiplying strings, which could go horribly wrong at some point.

Comment: Try to make a reduced test case. Include only code relevant to your problem, leave everything else out.

Answer (score 1):

This would normally happen in ASP.NET/web apps (and can be turned off) however yours is a winforms application so it should not happen unless you have some 3rd party component installed in your system doing this for you. you would need to switch THAT component off.

Now, you did NOT specify where it happens. if its a dropdownlist, then yes, it will autocomplete (part of the Windows/IE settings). if its a textbox, then not much explainable.

to switch it off for the dropdownlist, set the AutoCompleteMode to "none" in the designer. Same applies for the textbox too if there is a custom source being bound to it.

also this looks interesting:

```
 txtPriceAmount.Text = InventoryProduct(RowInteger).PriceDecimal.ToString("C2")
```

This could be the problem too, perhaps your RowInteger is not being updated correctly in your code somewhere and thus you are thinking it remembers the previous input but actually its just the wrong index.

Comment: how would I fix the string currency

Answer (score 0):

That code in the keypress event is very likely to blame.  Remark out the procedure and see if it goes away.

Since `strCurrency` is not declared in that procedure it must have a larger `scope` and so it "remembers" from the last time (especially since you do not initialize it in the procedure).

Rule #32 == LESS code is more better.

Rule 32a== Almost anytime you are tracking user's keystrokes, you are either solving the wrong problem or solving it the wrong way.

Edit:

As Andrew mentioned, this is wrong too:

```
ProductSalesTotalDecimal(IndexInteger) += _
       (txtPriceAmount.Text * txtQuantityAmount.Text)
```

Just as you cant multiple "cat" times "bicycle" you cant multiply the (string) content of textboxes even if they have numerals in them.

Comment: what would you suggest here

Comment: remark out the keypress event code.  if the problem goes away, problem solved.